# How to Create Bulk workItems in TFS as Bugs from c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, tfs

Currently i am creating workItems as Bugs from c# code using TFS Sdk. I have around some 5k bugs which I query from Sql Server Db Paging by 1000 then creating workItems into TFS. But for Creating 1000 WorkItems and saving into TFS its taking more then 15min. 
Following is my creation of workItems

```
foreach (var item in listbugs)
                            {
                                var workItem = new WorkItem(workItemTypes["bug"]);
                                workItem.Title = "newTitle";
                                workItem.Fields["repro steps"].Value = "Rerpoducible Step";
                                workItem.Save();
                            }
```

So if u guys know how to do create Bulk workItems please share the knowledge.
Thanks you help is greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130338%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) states:

> Every time you save a work item to Team Foundation Server, you generate a round-trip operation between the work item object model and the server. To minimize the round-trips when saving several work items, use the BatchSave method.

Documentation for BatchSave: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140385%28v=vs.90%29.aspx